# MySQL from Java: Inserting a default value using a PreparedStatement INSERT query parameter

Tags: java, mysql

Given a table with a field which has a default value, say like `something` here:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    time DATETIME PRIMARY KEY,
    something CHAR (16) DEFAULT 'a default',
);
```

... and a prepared statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (time, something) VALUES (?, ?)
```

How does one then opt to insert the default value of `something`?

I know I can get it by omitting the field.  However in my case I want to, in the same query, set the value in some records, and defer to the database to insert whatever is configured as the the default value in others.

Here's an example code snippet:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO foo (time, s1, s2, s3, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ...)";
// Many fields. You get the picture.

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
connection.setAutoCommit(false);

// Insert the lines.  The number of fields can change from one line to
// the next, depending on the sensors fitted at the time. The mapping
// of fields -> database values is defined by the enum Fields.
Field badField = null;
try {
    for(String line: loglines) {

        String loggedSensors[] = line.toString().split (",");
        for(Field field : Field.values()) {
             if (field.parseIndex >= loggedSensors.length) {
                 log.warning("using default value for absent field" +
                     field.columnName);
                 // Omitting the field generates an error. 
                 // How do we set the field to a default here?
                 continue;
             }
             badField = field;
             stmt.setObject(
                 field.ordinal()+1, 
                 field.parse(loggedSensors[field.parseIndex]));
        }
        stmt.addBatch();
        stmt.executeBatch();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("error inserting field "+badField, e);
    return;
}
connection.commit();
```

I've Googled and checked the documentation here, without finding anything which answers this specifically for MySQL:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference.html

Comment: why you don't use a condition?

Comment: @YCF_L: can you elaborate?

Comment: i mean `if(<condition>){//use default}else{//insert the new value}`, can you please share some code so we can understand?

Comment: @YCF_L: example added. I'd prefer to avoid that sort of condition, since the number of  alternative cases is at least equal to the number of fields (in my example), and in principle could be combinatorial, since each field can be present or absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workable solution seems to be to construct the query to use the MySQL `COALESCE()` and `DEFAULT()` functions to map nulls into defaults. So rewrite the example insert query like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (time, something) VALUES (?, COALESCE(?, DEFAULT(something)))
```

Then if we insert null into the second parameter, it will instead insert the default (which may of course, also be null):

```
// ...
    for(Field field : Field.values()) {
        if (field.parseIndex >= loggedSensors.length) {
            // MySQL permits setting null like this, other DBs may
            // require #setNull(int, int)
            stmt.setObject(field.ordinal()+1, null); 
        else
            stmt.setObject(
                field.ordinal()+1, 
                field.parse(loggedSensors[field.parseIndex]));
    }
// ...
```

Can be generalised for as many fields as you wish.  Although note that the field named inside `DEFAULT()` *must* have a default defined or there will be an error even if the default is not used.

Answer (score -2):

Don't specify the field in the INSERT statment and the default value will be used.

INSERT into foo (time) VALUES (?);

Comment: OP wrote "I know I can get it by omitting the field."